# How do I port forward from my host to docker container?

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, wireguard, mesh

I am running netmaker which is a wireguard mesh VPN service on a Docker container, and I need port 9981 to be reachable from the Docker container, so that I can access port 9981 via my Wireguard WAN.

Port 9981 is open on the VPS on which Netmaker is hosted, but isn't reachable from within the Docker container. I have been trying to no avail to get this right, and I'm now at my wits end.

I was advised to add this line to my docker-container file which has just caused error after error -

```
PORT_FORWARD_SERVICES="127.0.0.1:9981:9981"
```

Please can someone assist.

Comment: Please specify which instructions you used to start the container (and include them in your post). It's purely guessing from my side, until you provide some more details.

Comment: Imo, this is a docker question and not related to Ubuntu. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) on stackoverflow for an answer.

Comment: I don't see why [Docker questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/docker) would be off-topic?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)? Port forwarding is a pretty standard feature in Docker.

In a normal CLI syntax you add:

```
-p <host-port>:<container-port>
```

This is an example command that maps port 443:

```
docker run -d \
  --name=nextcloud \
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -e TZ=Europe/London \
  -p 443:443 \
  -v /path/to/appdata:/config \
  -v /path/to/data:/data \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  lscr.io/linuxserver/nextcloud:latest
```

So you need to add `-p 9981:9981` to the command you use to run your container.

There is also a similar syntax if you use Docker Compose (but since you didn't specify I assume this isn't the case).

Comment: I think OP needs to connect to a port on the host from inside the container, so he needs to [add `--network host` or `--add-host ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: In that case, the title is completely misleading - I'll leave my answer as long as the title says "port forward from my host to docker container" - but I'll remove it if it's no longer relevant.